# BeautifulSoup returns None even though element exists

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the table from this website:
https://maya.tase.co.il/funds?view=all

When I look into the backend code, I found out this Class for the first cell (right to left):
tableCol col_1 ng-scope

Now, my code is the following:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


URL = 'https://maya.tase.co.il/funds?view=all'
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

results = soup.find('div',{'class':'tableCol col_1 ng-scope'})

print(results)
```

But when running the above I get None as the result.
This is the case when I try different elements as well.
Anyone knows a possible solution to this?
Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Thank in advance,
Uri

Comment: The entire site is behind `JavaScript` so either explore `selenium` or check if there's an `API` because you won't scrape that site with `bs4`, at it simply doesn't *see* dynamic content.

Comment: Another option is to use a proxy service that is capable of rendering JS loaded content. An example that can do it is ProxyCrawl. It's a paid service- I'm not affiliated with them.

Comment: FYI ‘To scrap’ (and scrapping/scrapper/scrapped) means to throw away, to discard. Use scrape/scraping/scraper/scraped

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from selenium import webdriver
import time
url = 'https://maya.tase.co.il/funds?view=all'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(10)
soup_page=driver.page_source
soup_page=soup(driver.page_source,'html.parser')
time.sleep(20)
results=soup_page.find('div',{'class':'tableCol col_1 ng-scope'}).text
print(results)
```

The `time.sleep()` are there to let load the page properly.